# Removing 300ms delay in ionicModal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an app based on Ionic 1.So i need to have a two modal dialog in a step-series as describe in picture below.

[image]
I need to disable the animation (as well as the 300ms opacity change) as it should not be any animation between or flickering when in the transition of modal 1 to modal 2 (to prevent the ionic view to be shown to user in the 300ms transitioning). Anyway, the decision is i need to disable the transition animation.

So this lead to another problem to me:
- since the Close modal link lies directly in the position of select dropdown, the dropdown selection will be trigger due to the 300ms delay. How should i resolve this problem? I am looking more forward for an elegant way rather then doing something like put a div to overlay modal dialog 2 and remove it in 300ms timeout

```
<a ng-click="closeModal()">Close modal</a>

angular.module('testApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: none
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
    $scope.openModal2();
  };

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal-2.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: none
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal2 = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal2 = function() {
    $scope.modal2.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal2 = function() {
    $scope.modal2.hide();
  };
});
```

Comment: You used the `animation:none` property, and as far as i know that should do the trick, beeing the build in way but you can try canceling it using css :  `#login-modal{ transform:none !important; -webkit-transform:none !important; }`. Never had a case with 2 modals, but i saw this in a project and i seemed to be just fine, cancelling the whole effect.

Comment: @Stefan.B hi i have resolve the animation issue, what i am concerning is the 300ms delay that results in the select option to be popup once the modal dialog 2 is shown